# SIPP, send multiple Via

Tags: sip, sipp

I'm trying to send multiple Via's from SIPP:

```
Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port];branch=[branch]
Via:  SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:5080;branch=[branch]
```

However, this approach doesn't work. What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried exactly as you said and it worked.
Maybe your problem is not in this specific part.
In my test, I sent this message:

```
  INVITE sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port] SIP/2.0
  Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port];branch=[branch]
  Via:  SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:5080;branch=[branch]
  From: sipp <sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]>;tag=[call_number]
  To: sut <sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port]>
  Call-ID: [call_id]
  CSeq: 1 INVITE
  Contact: sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]
  Max-Forwards: 70
  Subject: Performance Test
  Content-Type: application/sdp
  Content-Length: [len]

  v=0
  o=user1 53655765 2353687637 IN IP[local_ip_type] [local_ip]
  s=-
  c=IN IP[media_ip_type] [media_ip]
  t=0 0
  m=audio [media_port] RTP/AVP 0
  a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which version did you use?

Comment: SIPp v3.4-beta1 (aka v3.3.990)